# Jqgrid - How to create a custom add-button that you can supply of parameters

Tags: jqgrid

When you create a jqgrid there is a default button on the bottom of the grid that allows you to create new records.

However, when you open the modal, all input fields are empty.

In my situation I need this button, but I also need the exact same thing but with the possibilty of adding a few parameters so some of the fields are already filled in. The parameters would come from the selected row at that moment.

Like when I click a row where the date is set to 01/01/2099 i need the add-modal to open with the date already set to that date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `beforeShowForm` or `afterShowForm` to make *any* changes in the Add Form during opening. For example you can read the values from currently selected row and fill some fields of the form with new values. To be open Add form on click or double-click on the row you need just call [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#adding_row) inside of `onSelectRow`/`ondblClickRow` callback.